# bootstrap custom alert close on click and for x amount of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to do is to add to a custom message box a time function to keep the message box hidden for x amount of time, but only when the user click on the appropriate button. (dismiss)

I'm trying to take advantage of bootstrap but now I think I need some jquery code as well.

this is what I 'm using to show the message:

```
 <div class="notifier-box">
         <div class="custompm fade" id="message1">
           <p><a href="{U_PRIVATEMSGS}"> {L_YOU_HAVE} {PRIVATE_MESSAGE_INFO</a></p>
           <button data-dismiss="alert" class="btn btn-small">{L_DISMISS}</button>
         </div>
    </div>
```

with this function:

```
<script>
head.ready(function () {
// some callback stuff
$('#message1').toggleClass('in');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you check the correct implementation of Bootstrap Alerts (some examples [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts)):

```
<div class="alert alert-warning fade in" id="message1">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

Using jQuery you need to setup a timer to *auto* dismiss alert box, and bind an event to the button who will dismiss the alert with a click:

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
         $("#message1").alert('close');
    },3000); // milliseconds to auto dismiss

    $("#button_dismiss").on('click', function(){
         $("#message1").alert('close');
    });
});
```

**Update:** According to your comments:

```
<div id="message1">I am an alert!</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        // Set a global timeout handler
        var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function(){
            $("#message1").addClass('hide');
        }, 2000);

        $("#some-button").on('click', function(){
            // Clear current timeout
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

            $("#message1").removeClass('hide');
            timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function(){
                $("#message1").addClass('hide');
            }, 2000);
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry I think I didnt explaing myself properly. Basically I want to add a timer function on the click. so if the user clicks on dismiss the custom notification will stay hidden for x amount of seconds even if they refresh the page. Right now the popup fires automatically whenever there is a message. so if the user does not read the message the popup will always be shown. Do you know what I'm saying by this?

Comment: Got it. You can try use [this plugin](http://rendro.github.io/countdown/), check the options and methods.

Comment: Yeah I saw that one. I didnt want to use any extra scripts. How can Integrate something like this on click, so that it will hide my custom alert and set the timeout to stay hidden?

$('#some-button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
setTimeout('enableButton()', 5000);

function enableButton(){
   $('#some-button').removeAttr('disabled');
}

Comment: I have updated the answer with a sample code according to your comments